# slow keyboard layout switching in gnome 3.6

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-3

when I upgraded from gnome 3.4 to gnome 3.6 I realized that I could not change my keyboard layout using Alt+Shift anymore. so I installed gnome-tweak-tool and in Typing tab I selected Alt+Shift from Modifiers-only input sources.

now I can change my layouts using Alt+Shift but it is really slow ... what should I do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is because now in gnome 3.6 gnome handles input sources instead of x. you can disable gnome from handling keyboard layouts :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

then install qxkb and configure it for your own.

now x handles your keyboard layout and it is fast :).

Comment: Hey @Mohammad, I'm having the same problem. Unfortunately this does not work for me for some reason. Is there another way?

Comment: Thanks, but how to indicate current layout? When X handles it, standard GNOME indicator doesn't work.

Comment: I got `No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard”` in Gnome 40.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME Shell 3.28.1) I also noticed lags when switching layouts through `Alt+Shift`. At 16.04 this was not.

I noticed that if I use the standard `Super+Space` combination, it works faster.

**I found this solution:** https://askubuntu.com/a/986629/766670

The bottom line is that `Alt+Shift` is an add-on combination of switching (slow), but the standard - fast.

Therefore, you can replace the key combination of the standard method with the desired one and switching **will work faster**:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

I hope this helps someone to avoid wasting time on finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following Gnome-shell extension exactly for this big keyboard-switch latency: [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/).

> The language switcher popup by default takes ~0.7sec to appear, meaning that roughly 2-4 strokes are lost till the switch completes. This affects heavily users typing languages with non-latin based alphabets (e.g. Greek, Cyrilic, Arabic, Japanese), particularly when writting technical documents.
> This extension reduces the switching time to 1/10th of a second (on a 2019 PC).